# LDAP change/reset password c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, ldap

I tried to change/reset password to user that has to change his password after first login using c#

My code:

```
var domain = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ONLINE-AD"];
directoryEntry.Username = userName;
directoryEntry.Password = password;
var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
SearchResult result = directorySearcher.FindOne();
if (result != null)
  {
    DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    if (userEntry != null)
    {
      userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", model.Resetpassword);
      userEntry.CommitChanges();
     }
   }
```

But when I tried to do `FindOne()` i got an error `773` (means that the user has to change password for first time)

here is the error :
[image]

**How to access user using LDAP ?(I successed to do login with
proper user)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created **Admin** user that can manage all users then I got all users using the admin and find the wanted user and set password to this user:

```
public string ResetPassword(LoginDTO model) {
  try {
    //get context by admin user

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ONLINE-AD"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminName"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPassword"]);

    //find the wanted user
    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, model.UserName);

    if (user != null) {
      try {
        user.ChangePassword(model.Password, model.NewPassword);
      } catch {
        return "-1";
      }

    }

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    return "-1";
  }
  return "1"
}
```